# Built-in webcam not available

Tags: drivers, 20.04, webcam

My built-in webcam is no longer working.

Here's some diagnostics, from similar questions:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.

$ ls /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
marco@marco-Predator-P
```

Any ideas suggestions?

Comment: `My built-in webcam is no longer working.` -- Did it work before? Was there any update after which it stopped working? Can you trying booting from an older kernel to check if it works there?

Comment: Yes, it worked a few months ago - I've since done software updates a few times (but not Ubuntu itself, that's still 20.04)